# Downloading an Image from WebBrowser, copying it on Clipboard on VBA

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, gdi+, clipboard, bmp

Im having problems with a code for downloading images from a web page using WebBrowser in VBA.

The code is as follows:

Private Function downloadImage(name As String, index As Integer, path As String, IDName As String)

```
    Dim objDoc As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)
    Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = (CType(objDoc.body, HTMLBody)).createControlRange()

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim count2 As Integer = 0

    For Each img As IHTMLImgElement In objDoc.images
        If Not IsNothing(img.id) Then
            If img.id.Equals(name) And count.Equals(index) Then

                imgRange.add(CType(img, IHTMLControlElement))
                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
                Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
                bmp.Save(path & IDName & ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                count = count + 1
            ElseIf img.id.Equals(name) Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
        count2 = count2 + 1
    Next
    Return path & IDName
End Function
```

The problem is, at the line bmp.Save(path & IDName & ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp), it gives me the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Error genérico en GDI+.

I will try looking and testing for an answer, and update if i found something.

Thanks for the help!

Looking for this error, on other posts and at other forums/webpages, i've found that it is common when the memory stream is closed before saving... But i haven't close the memory stream.

One requirement of the problem is that the src can't be used, the image is sent using https, and later deleted, that's why i used the clipboard.

**UPDATE**:
The code is right, what was wrong was my brain.

Wrong file path, exception at GDI+...

I will left this code up, for maybe helping someone